# how to use sqlite select query with LIKE operator in c# uwp

Tags: c#, windows, sqlite

How to use sqlite Select query with LIKE operator. I am working with sqlite in uwp app. I am not able to use SqliteCommand class over here. Can anyone sugest me.

```
using (db = new SQLiteConnection(new SQLitePlatformWinRT(), db.DatabasePath))
{
    var result = db.Query<Sku_Price_List>(@"SELECT * FROM Sku_Price_List WHERE sku_id LIKE '%eve%' OR sale_price LIKE '%eve%'  OR description LIKE '%eve%'");
}
```

this code is working but with like operator i want to pass the string dynamically. Help me.

Comment: What is your question? And what has this to do with Uwp and Wpf?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have it in method like:

```
public Sku_Price_List GetPriceList(string likeCriterion) {
    using (db = new SQLiteConnection(new SQLitePlatformWinRT(), db.DatabasePath))
    {
        var result = db.Query<Sku_Price_List>(@"SELECT * FROM Sku_Price_List WHERE sku_id LIKE '%"+likeCriterion+"%' OR sale_price LIKE '%"+likeCriterion+"%'  OR description LIKE '%"+likeCriterion+"%'");
        return result;
    }  
}
```

That can be simplified by using new C# 6.0 syntax:

```
var result = db.Query<Sku_Price_List>($"SELECT * FROM Sku_Price_List WHERE sku_id LIKE '%{likeCriterion}%' OR sale_price LIKE '%{likeCriterion}%'  OR description LIKE '%{likeCriterion}%'");
```